# What sql data type should I use to store execution time in milliseconds?

Tags: sql, types, execution-time

I need to store the execution time (in milliseconds) of a function in a sql field. What data type should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `int` would be the best type for you.

Comment: Thanks! Was planning on using an int, but just wanted confirmation... Is it definitely big enough, even for large execution times?

Comment: @froadit - you need to figure out what the largest expected execution time is and then see if it fits into the int32 bounds - we can't do that for you.

Comment: let's say you use int with a length of 20. This means the biggest number would be 99999999999999999999 (dont even try to rea it), it means 99999999999999999999/(1000*3600*24) = 1150000000000 days. Is it enough for you?

Comment: 32-bit (4 billion) milliseconds equal about 49 days. 32-bit seconds equal about 136 years.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a standard 32-bit integer (or whatever comes close in your RDBMS). If your RDBMS has a specific type for timespans, use that, but all RDBMS that I know of only have timestamp-like data types.

**Added:** A 32-bit integer is enough for [a bit over 49 days](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216641). If you need longer than that, you'll have to use a bigger data type, but then I doubt you'll need a millisecond precision. At a second precision it is good for about [136 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp#Representing_the_number). If you need more than that, you've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider storing your elapsed time in 2 columns (a 32-bit `int` for the seconds, and a 16-bit `smallint` for the milliseconds). That will cover a range of some 68 years and take 6 bytes per row.

Alternatively, storing your elapsed time in the `money` data type, as seconds, is convenient. It stores 4 decimal places of precision and has a range of c. -2^3 to +2^63 - 1, or more precisely, -922,337,203,685,477.5808) through +922,337,203,685,477.5807. Discounting negative values, +922,337,203,685,477.5807 seconds covers some 29m years. Using `money` will take 8 bytes per row.

Or the `decimal(p,q)` datatype. Choose your overall precision `p` and number of decimal places `q`. Storage required is is 5, 9, 13, or 17 bytes depending on the value of `p`.